# How to Resolve ORA-27106: system pages not available to allocate memory?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I was working well before changing below code.

```
alter database archivelog;
alter system set sga_max_size = 20480M  scope=spfile;
```

Currently Error is

```
ORA-27106: system pages not available to allocate memory 
additional information 6128
```

Comment: When you do a web search on the ORA error code, what advice do you find from reputable sources, such as oracle.com?

Comment: No advice found from oracle.com

Comment: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2254167_1.html

Comment: That Oracle support article gives some great information on the causes of that ORA error as well as how to investigate and solve the problem. Without seeing the alert log file or knowing anything about your server specs, we won't be able to provide any help here other than guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Check shmmax kernel parameter and set to recommended value-
This parameter defines the maximum size in bytes of a single shared memory segment that a Linux process can allocate in its virtual address space.

Caution - when tying to allocate SGA size bigger than SHMMAX the error below occur.
“SGA size con not be greater than maximum shared memory segment size (shmmax value)”

If shm* parameter are set, then look at hugepages (it may be due to insufficient HugePages)

grep -huge /proc/meminfo

and try to free it.